# android development, db file does not get updated

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have created a database and put it under "databases" directory in my project(using eclipse). When I lunch an application for the second time after changing the database file, old database file from phone does not get deleted a new fresh copy is not installed to the phone. I was wondering if anyone experienced something like this?
Any possible solutions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that when just running the app from Eclipse after doing some file modifications, the old files that were on the phone stay. This includes Shared Preferences, db files etc...

Solution: ***To be sure that new files will be installed delete your app from your phone manually if this occurs, and then click Run in Eclipse.***

Also another bug that happens rarely to me is that i change the code and when running the app the old code executes? Eclipse gets into buggy state sometimes and needs to be restarted if you experience some weird behavior. (this used to happen to me with old ADT before update)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I am thinking what happens if the application goes to market and this happens on people's phones?
Is there a way to delete old files from previous application?

Comment: This wont happen on the market. The users are only able to download the app if they dont have it installed. This happens because of installing the app through eclipse. I have a db app on the market and non of these problems occurred after publishing.

Comment: Also you can write in app description, or have a dialog that will notify users if such problems occur to uninstall the app and install it again. Its not a big deal all the major popular apps like twitter for ex. have such issues. Another solution would be to have publish your app without the database, and have it downloaded on first run.

Comment: I uploaded my app to marker as alpha but when I installed from there, there was a conflict because there was still a database file from my eclipse testing. So I got an error.

Comment: Hmh, if thats the case i would recommend that you download the db on first run. That way you can control the database name/path/and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Android does not delete db file automatically from application.When you change the name of your previous db filename to new filename it creates new db file and also keep old db file.

Comment: if you want to remove your old db file from eclipse then you need to remove it manually from DDMS.After removing old db file your app load a new copy of db.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created A Sqlite database in my app firstly i am having the same problem then i created my new database name with the old name and replaced my old one .so i am agree with @ved it creates new db file and also keep old db file.

Comment: oh ok, but I did not change my database file name. Only tables were modified.

Comment: I created a database with the old name and replaced it.it working fine for me.

Comment: Can you explain how you do it? Maybe I missed a step?
All I did was to put db file in databases directory. Other than that, I did not do anything more on eclipse.

Comment: I just changed my database files name and new file did not got transfered to device.

Comment: First of clean your project then uninstall it from emulator or phone and then try to run your application.Hope it work for you.

Comment: @BlatheMag why don't you create external database with browser and try to implement like [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a helper class for database connection and the problem was gone.
You can find it here:
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper